# Alert a line of code from a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript error log and one of the columns is the line number where the error occurred. I think it would save me time from having to go through the source from the browser's perspective if I could just click the link and get a JavaScript `alert` with that line (or lines) of code.

So in short: how can I retrieve a specific line or lines of code from a JavaScript file that is included via a `script` element in the head of the code?

I don't use frameworks.

Comment: Do you mean the code itself or the line number? Also, is the code directly in the `<script>`, or an external JS file?

Comment: What is this "error log" you have? Is this some server-side report?

Comment: @trojansdestroy The external source code essentially *included* via the script element.

Comment: I'd suggest you show us exactly what error information you have to start with.  And, we need to know if the script line is in the main HTML file or in an included JS file?

Comment: TWICE I've stated the the **SCRIPT FILE IS INCLUDED**.

Comment: And you refuse to show us what error information you actually have to start with?  Why so hostile to people trying to help?  Geez.  Your question simply doesn't contain enough info for us to know the specifics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 It doesn't get more specific, it's not my fault if people don't read the question. I posted a *working* answer.

Comment: You never showed us what info you started with so how are we to know what you need to do to find the right source file and the actual line.  For example, did you have the script file name?  Did not know that simple info. You assumed way too much was understood by your readers which is perhaps why *nobody* posted an answer that did what you wanted.  Anyway, if you want to make it difficult for people to help you, then that's your prerogative.  I'll steer clear of nebulous questions where the OP refuses to help clarify.

Comment: Oh, and your answer always goes to the first script tag.  How are we (or you) to know that's the right script tag?  Insufficient information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution isn't perfect as it creates an unnecessary request to the server however it does exactly what I wanted to do...

```
function getLines(haystack,from,toIncluding)
{
 var i = 0
 var j = 0;
 var result = '';
 --from;

 while (from-- >0 && i !== -1)
 {
  --toIncluding, i = haystack.indexOf('\n', i + 1);
 }

 if (i===-1) {result = '';}
 j = i;

 while (toIncluding-->0 && j !== -1)
 {
  j = haystack.indexOf('\n', j + 1);
 }

 if (j === -1) {j = haystack.length;}

 result = haystack.slice(i + 1, j);
 return result;
}
```

...and then simply use...

```
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('GET',document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].src,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState=='4')
   {
    alert(getLines(xmlhttp.responseText,2,7));
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Modern day browsers ship with a debugging console. They log the error message and a stack trace whenever errors happen. Line numbers for the error and involved functions in the stack are usually provided and are *clickable to take you the the line* where it happened.

Comment: This adds an extra step and doesn't answer my question.